# How to make MongoDB as in-memory database (partially or fully) in Windows 8.1

Tags: mongodb, windows-8.1

I am using MongoDB as database for my spring web service.Now I want some data(if possible) or complete data should be transferred to mongodb database as in-memory database in ***Windows 8.1***.I tried searching how to make this in Windows but I couldn't find this.I only got for Linux http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis ,So can anyone tell me how to make this or can you share link where it is written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RAMDISK**

You could try setting up a ramdisk on windows, and then telling mongodb to use that location as the datastore.

You can configure this by setting the `storage.dbPath` in mongodb's configuration - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Here's a guide for setting up a ramdisk on windows - http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/

And you can start mongodb and pass in the `--dbpath` to point to the ramdisk

---

**'inMemoryExperiment' STORAGE ENGINE**

Also as of MongoDB v3 there is an experimental in memory storage engine, you can try it out by passing in `--storageEngine inMemoryExperiment` to the `mongod` command when starting mongodb

Some info here - http://stela.io/mongodb-in-memory-storage-engine-setup/

Comment: hey can just me in detail ?

Comment: Edited with some useful links

Comment: Hey thanx Matthew for telling this,but I tried with what explained in  http://stela.io/mongodb-in-memory-storage-engine-setup/ , running this in Command,for first 2 steps it is working fine but , for 3rd step error coming as **"The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185"**,can you tell me what I should change in 'Service Name' I absolutely dont know it ?

Comment: Hi Matthew again I think I have done as per given in http://stela.io/mongodb-in-memory-storage-engine-setup/ link,But how to really check whether MongoDB is currently working as in-memory database ?

Comment: If you are running it using the in memory engine, then I would guess its running as an in memory database

Comment: what do you mean by "running it using the in memory engine" ??you mean when we complete 3rd step on that link ?

Comment: yea if you follow the steps in the link then it will be running using the in memory engine, therefore it will be in memory!